# Rename monthnames in LaTeX

Tags: latex, renewcommand

I've got a seemingly small problem using LaTeX, which i can't find the answer for after quite a bit of internet searching...

I'm writing a schoolassignment in faroese, and want to change the \date(\today) names to faroese.

I guess i have to use the \renewcommand, but i don't know what i should put in there.

Basicly, i want to change the names as follow:

January --> Januar
February --> Februar
March --> Mars
etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Would better be asked at http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to define your own \today. To display Januar 15, 2011, put this above \begin{document}

```
\def\today{ifcase\month\or Januar\or Februar\or Mars ...etc... December\fi \space\number\day, \number\year}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are better off *not* doing this by hand, but letting the `babel` package take care of it. As a bonus, that also gives you correct hyphenation, caption names, etcetera. From [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Internationalization#Icelandic_.2F_Faroese):

```
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

(Since it's written there, I assume that `icelandic` is close enough to Faroese, but until five minutes ago, I didn't even know that the language existed...)

Comment: Now I just sound picky, but the spelling in icelandic and faroese is very different, although we use (almost) the same letters.

Comment: That's not picky at all, I'm just clueless about your language, sorry :) You could still include babel and fix up the cases where it goes wrong. (Or maybe you could do the world a favour: copy the `icelandic` language definition, modify it to work for Faroese, and publish it.)

Comment: Might just do that after this assignment (deadline is in a few hours), although seems like an overkill for 48.000 people (whereof i guess around 10 use latex)

Comment: @Gunnar *seems like an overkill* - it's good advertising for Latex if you do that, mind.  MS Word doesn't have a Faroese language pack, and I'm guessing it has more than 10 Faroese users.